# Is it possible to use the mute button as an input in programming?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

Hey so I was using Spotify yesterday and I noticed while an ad was playing that any time I mute my volume or drop the volume to zero, spotify pauses the ad and doesn't resume until you turn the volume back up. I started thinking about that and got curious, how exactly does that work? Could I theoretically make a java program that prints "false" every time I hit the mute button on my laptop? What are the topics to look up if I was interested in learning more about this? Would this have to do with assembly at all?

Comment: Yes that is possible I did that allready in C# but I have no idea how that could work in Java. If I remember correctly the trick was to hook the keyboard events.

Comment: Perhaps it checks the system volume periodically.

Comment: Hmm. This is interesting. :)

Comment: Spotify pauses the ad whenever the volume hits 0. I don't think they detect presses to 'mute', but rather monitor the mixer.

Comment: I am interested by your code, and I would like to collaborate on the little sample/snippet, can you please create a github ...

Answer (score 0):

I've never done something like that, but after a quick research on the web, I guess it can be achieved via the The [AudioSystem Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html). You can find a [tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html).